# Extracting different fields and tables ORACLE R12 TABLES

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a problem of joining the tables of Oracle r12 tables. I have tried something like this..

```
SELECT
     part.party_name,
     custA.account_number,
     headAll.cust_po_number,
     headAll.order_number,
     trans.NAME,
     headAll.ordered_date,
     sales.person_name,
     headAll.flow_status_code,
     items.segment1,
     lineAll.ordered_quantity,
     lineAll.order_quantity_uom,
     lineAll.unit_selling_price,
     lineAll.tax_code
FROM
     oe_order_headers_all headAll,
     oe_order_lines_all lineAll,
     hz_cust_accounts custA,
     hz_parties part,
     oe_transaction_types_tl trans,
     hz_person_profiles sales,
     mtl_system_items_b items
WHERE
     headAll.Header_ID       = lineAll.Header_ID
 AND custA.Application_ID    = part.Application_ID
 AND custA.Application_ID    = sales.Application_ID
 AND items.inventory_item_id = lineAll.inventory_item_id;
```

It is running but I know it is wrong because it is multiplying tables. Any Ideas of r12 tables in Oracle and combining this sample r12 tables?

```
-oe_order_headers_all 
-oe_order_lines_all
-hz_cust_accounts
-hz_parties
-oe_transaction_types_tl
-hz_person_profiles
-mtl_system_items_b
```

I Tried this..

Updated:

```
 from oe_order_headers_all headAll
 INNER JOIN
 oe_order_lines_all lineAll
 ON headAll.Header_ID = lineAll.Header_ID
 INNER JOIN
 hz_cust_accounts custA 
 ON headAll.sold_to_org_id = custA.cust_account_id
 INNER JOIN
 hz_parties part
 ON custA.party_id = part.party_id 
 INNER JOIN
 oe_transaction_types_tl trans
 ON headAll.order_type_id = trans.transaction_type_id
 INNER JOIN
 hz_person_profiles sales 
 ON part.party_id = sales.party_id
 INNER JOIN
 mtl_system_items_b items 
 ON items.inventory_item_id = lineAll.inventory_item_id
```

And I Tried Where Clause

```
 where headAll.Header_ID = lineAll.Header_ID AND headAll.order_type_id = trans.transaction_type_id  AND custA.party_id = part.party_id 
 AND part.party_id = sales.party_id AND headAll.sold_to_org_id = custA.cust_account_id AND items.inventory_item_id = lineAll.inventory_item_id;
```

Still multiplying..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about having Oracle R12 suite. In general any Oracle engine will behave like this.
Let me show you some examples.

```
TABLE A
- COL1 PK1
- COL2 PK1
- COL3

TABLE B
- COL4 PK2
- COL5 PK2
- COL6

TABLE C
- COL7 
- COL8 -PK3
- COL9 -PK3
```

In this model, whenever we join any tables unless you join on their key combinations or based on the rule that for any given row you retrieve a maximum of one row from the other table.

```
SELECT A.COL1
FROM   TABLEA, TABLEB
WHERE  COL1 = COL4
AND    COL2 = COL5;
```

OR in ANSI syntax

```
SELECT A.COL1
FROM   TABLEA 
JOIN TABLEB ON COL1 = COL4 AND COL2 = COL5;
```

So this can be extended on the third table.

```
SELECT A.COL1
FROM   TABLEA, TABLEB, TABLEC
WHERE  COL1 = COL4
AND    COL2 = COL5
AND    COL1 = COL8
AND    COL2 = COL9;
```

**PS:** The assumption is that the combined primary key on both the tables will always provide one row for the other.

You need to extend your ON clauses to include a condition so that for each entry in TABLE A there is only one entry in TABLE B that matches the condition and that for each entry in TABLE B there is only one entry in TABLE C

You can always try to join tables one by one and keep the query building until and unless you done violate the thumb rule (said above).

If, I change the join condition and any table duplicates while performing the same, then the same will be propagated to the subsequent joins.

Answer (score 0):

There are not all relations between tables. Alias **trans** isn't related at all, groups **headAll, lineAll, items** and **custA, part, sales** are separated. In this case rows will be joined with default [cross join](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html).

Add conditions in the WHERE clause:

```
AND headAll.order_type_id = trans.transaction_type_id

AND headAll.sold_to_org_id = custA.cust_account_id
```

Please see this example from Oracle tutorial: [Query to get the OM Sales Order summary details](http://iamlegand.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/query-to-get-the-om-sales-order-summary-details/)

Comment: how can I cross join those tables sir? can you give me example?

Comment: it is still multiplying tables.

Comment: I've corrected my answer, i found absent conditions in the given sample from the tutorial

Comment: it is still multipliying I tried JOIN. updated above my question. and also i tried where clause.

Comment: Did you check WHERE with added conditions? WHERE  headAll.order_type_id = trans.transaction_type_id
 AND headAll.sold_to_org_id = custA.cust_account_id
 AND headAll.Header_ID       = lineAll.Header_ID
 AND custA.Application_ID    = part.Application_ID
 AND custA.Application_ID    = sales.Application_ID
 AND items.inventory_item_id = lineAll.inventory_item_id;